# How to link libs in Xcode7

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I update Xcode to 7.0. Then I build the project then get errors below.I have try the solution the add the lib "libsqlite3.dylib" and "libz.dylib" to "Link Binary With Libraries" manually. But it doesn't work.

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/lib/libz.dylib (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove all references to .framework and .dylib files under Xcode 7. libcocos2d is a static library and therefore there is no link phase. You can only link in .framework and .dylib files in your game's project file.

[image: After removing the binaries, the Build Phases should like this:]